# build a query with conditional where clause in eloquent model

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, builder

I need to build a query with eloquent model including conditional where clause. I created something by searching google. But it doesn't seems to be working.

```
if ($status) {
    $this->where('status', $status);
}
if ($assignedto) {
    $this->where('assigned_to', $assignedto);
}
if ($fromDate != null && $toDate != null) {
    $this->whereBetween('date', array($fromDate, $toDate));
}
$quotes = $this->orderBy('date', 'desc')->paginate(40);
```

This one returns all results without the filtering of status, assigned to and dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just updated it by assigning `$this`  to a new variable because when I assigned the query to `$this`, it shown an error, `$this` cannot be over written.

```
$quoteModel = $this;
if ($status) {
    $quoteModel = $quoteModel->where('status', $status);
}
if ($assignedto) {
    $quoteModel = $quoteModel->where('assigned_to', $assignedto);
}
if ($fromDate != null && $toDate != null) {
    $quoteModel = $quoteModel->whereBetween('date', array($fromDate, $toDate));
}
$quotes = $quoteModel->orderBy('date', 'desc')->paginate(40);
```

which works perfectly now. But if somebody have some better option, please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I added a scope to my model and call it from the controller. This way the actual filtering work is done in the model, the controller is just running the query through the filter scope.

**Model:**

I am getting URL parameters with `Input::get`, but you would also pass them as input parameters to the function.

```
public function scopeFilter($query)
{
    $published = Input::get('published');
    if (isset($published)) $query->where('published', '=', $published);

    return $query;
}
```

**Controller:**

Here the query is run through the `filter()` before returning it to the view.

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('articles.index', [
        'articles' => Article::with('writer')->filter()->get()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good method. but while developing bigger apps, when you need to work with so many tables and models, this doesn't seems to be practical. I'm not sure. it's just a guess.